# Google Maps API: get default location and put it into a variable

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On load, I'm setting up the map:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
    });
```

I have a variable called `current_location` that I need to populate with what is essentially `40, -100` ... or the default `LatLng` that I've declared above.

What is the method to get this? `google.maps.getLatLng` or something similar??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var current_location = map.getCenter();
```

Or you could say:

```
var current_location = new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100);
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    center: current_location,
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
});
```